# react-hook-form watch for text of select not the value

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

```
const { myDropDown} = watch();
```

returns the value of that, but is there a way with watch() to get the actual text of the select?

As an example my select might be

```
<select name="myDropDown">
    <option value="1">Cheese</option>
    <option value="2">Ham</option>
</select>
```

`watch()` as used above will return me 1 or 2 but I want it to return me Cheese or Ham.

[Docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) didn't seem to help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because this is an old question, but in [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/watch) they do register the element, anyways, this is secondary:

```js
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Test = () => {
  const { register, watch, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const myDropDown = watch("myDropDown");

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(myDropDown);
    //...
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <select {...register("myDropDown")}>
          <option value="1">Cheese</option>
          <option value="2">Ham</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

in the above example, yes when you submit to see the value of `myDropDown`, it is either `1` or `2` because those are the values of the options, like in text input for example, you want to watch changes on the `value`.

that being said, the easiest way that comes to mind is to use the same children of the option element as `value`:

```js
<select name="myDropDown">
  <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
  <option value="Ham">Ham</option>
</select>
```

this will work as expected, if you want to keep the values as numbers, maybe you use them in another task, then you really lose a lot of the benefits of `watch` but you can still manage that.

in the same link you can see how they put `watch` inside the dependency array of `useEffect`, it is the "Callback version of watch", this will be like an `onChange` event lister to the `select` element, so we can take advantage of it and set the corresponding value to a `ref`, lets call it `myDropDownResult` and use it instead when you submit the form:

```js
const Test = () => {
  const { register, watch, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const myDropDown = watch("myDropDown");
  const myDropDownResult = useRef("Cheese");

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(myDropDownResult.current);
    // when you submit the form use "myDropDownResult.current"
    //...
  };

  // Callback version of watch.  It's your responsibility to unsubscribe when done.
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = watch((value) => {
      if (value.myDropDown == 1) { 
        myDropDownResult.current = "Cheese";
      } else {
        myDropDownResult.current = "Ham";
      }
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [watch]);

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <select {...register("myDropDown")}>
          <option value="1">Cheese</option>
          <option value="2">Ham</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

binding `myDropDown` and `myDropDownResult` may be more complicated, here, the example was basic, but the options can be rendered dynamically, so you may need to give a `ref` to `<select>` so you can access its children then find the option with the corresponding `value` so you can retrieve its children and finally set it to `myDropDownResult`, you got the idea but **options' values should be unique**

Answer (score -1):

Had a quick look at the docs, seems like you can to pass watch a parameter.

Like so:

```
  const watchFields = watch(["showAge", "number"]); // you can also target specific fields by their names
```

Did you try that?

Found a sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-with-ui-library-ts-forked-kn3t1?file=/src/index.tsx:1073-1083)
They wrap a Controller around it and use a DropdownListComponent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah i think it's just a different way of writing const { myDropDown} = watch();

Comment: Did the link I added above help?